# Cucumber tests running twice with spork on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, spork

I am running on windows7.

I can run cucumber with & without spork.

Without spork it is dead slow.
With Spork the tests run twice, Any ideas why please ?

If I start up spork:

```
bundle exec spork cucumber
```

& then run the tests using cucumber the tests first run dead quick, I get the following output

```
Spork is no longer supported as of Cucumber 1.3.0. Please downgrade to version 1.2.5 Disabling profiles...

.....test o/p

10 scenarios (10 passed) 69 steps (69 passed) 0m1.010s WARNING: No DRb server is running. Running features locally: WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      builder (>= 2.1.2, ~> 3.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, ~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Please report a bug if this causes problems. DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle Using the default profile... Feature: authentication pages

.....test o/p
```

And then the tests rerun again but slowly as if spork is not running.

rails --version

```
rails --version
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Rails 4.1.1
```

bundle show

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app2>bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.1.1)
  * actionpack (4.1.1)
  * actionview (4.1.1)
  * activemodel (4.1.1)
  * activerecord (4.1.1)
  * activesupport (4.1.1)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * bcrypt (3.1.7)
  * bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.0)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.3.5)
  * capybara (2.3.0)
  * celluloid (0.15.2)
  * childprocess (0.5.3)
  * coderay (1.1.0)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
  * cucumber (1.3.15)
  * cucumber-rails (1.4.1)
  * database_cleaner (1.3.0)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.2.0)
  * factory_girl (4.2.0)
  * factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
  * ffi (1.9.3)
  * formatador (0.2.5)
  * gherkin (2.12.2)
  * guard (2.6.1)
  * guard-spork (1.5.1)
  * haml (4.0.5)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.9)
  * jbuilder (2.1.0)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.0)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * listen (2.7.7)
  * lumberjack (1.0.6)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * method_source (0.8.2)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * mini_portile (0.6.0)
  * minitest (5.3.4)
  * multi_json (1.10.1)
  * multi_test (0.1.1)
  * nokogiri (1.6.2.1)
  * pg (0.17.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.5)
  * pry (0.10.0)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.1.1)
  * rails_12factor (0.0.2)
  * rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
  * rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
  * railties (4.1.1)
  * rake (10.3.2)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.5)
  * rdoc (4.1.1)
  * rspec-collection_matchers (1.0.0)
  * rspec-core (2.99.0)
  * rspec-expectations (2.99.0)
  * rspec-its (1.0.1)
  * rspec-mocks (2.99.0)
  * rspec-rails (2.99.0)
  * sass (3.2.19)
  * sass-rails (4.0.3)
  * sdoc (0.4.0)
  * shoulda-matchers (2.6.1)
  * slop (3.5.0)
  * spork (1.0.0rc4)
  * spork-rails (4.0.0)
  * spring (1.1.3)
  * sprockets (2.11.0)
  * sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.9)
  * therubyrhino (2.0.3)
  * therubyrhino_jar (1.7.4)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.4)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * timers (1.1.0)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * turbolinks (2.2.2)
  * tzinfo (1.2.1)
  * tzinfo-data (1.2014.3)
  * uglifier (2.5.0)
  * win32-process (0.7.4)
  * win32console (1.3.2)
  * xpath (2.0.0)
```

gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.2'


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development


gem 'execjs'
#gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'therubyrhino'
gem 'haml'
gem 'sass'

gem 'tzinfo-data'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'  
  gem 'rspec-its'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'spork-rails' #, '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork' #, '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess' #, '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails',require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
  #gem 'factory_girl'
end


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

The only reference on the web to the message below that I can find tells me I can ignore this. I have tried mmessing about with gem versions of cucumber & cucumber-rails but I always get stacktraces.

```
Spork is no longer supported as of Cucumber 1.3.0. Please downgrade to version 1.2.5 Disabling profiles...
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.

I know this is not the correct answer but in the absence of anything else, this works

In file C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\cucumber-1.3.15\lib\cucumber\cli\drb_client.rb I commented out the raising of the Exception on line 24 as in:

```
rescue DRb::DRbConnError
STDERR.puts DRbClientError
#commented by BillComer
  #raise DRbClientError, "No DRb server is running."
```

the disadvantage with this is that you have to be running Spork because commenting this out actually disables the code referring back to run the non spork variant.